# Expectation of a function that is concave on a parameter is still concave?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, expected-value

Assume I have a function $g(x,c)$, where $x$ is a random variable and $c$ is deterministic. Assume that for all $x$, $g(x,c)$ is strictly concave in $c$.

Is it true that

$$ G(c) \equiv \mathbb{E}_{x}\left[g(x,c) \right] = \int g(x,c) dF(x) $$

is concave in $c$ as well?

Comment: Have you tried to verify the concavity condition for $G$?

Comment: Yes, however, I am always worried about the integral doing weird stuff

Comment: Just start with $G(\lambda c_1 + (1-\lambda)c_2) = \int \ldots$, use that $g(x, c)$ is concave in $c$, etc. It is really a straight-forward calculation.

Comment: I see! thanks!!